# Effects clubbing CSS properties on performance

Tags: css, performance

Will clubbing of CSS properties affect performance/render time of a page?
Is `background:url(smiley.gif) top left no-repeat` better than `background-image:url(smiley.gif);background-position:top left;background-repeat:no-repeat;`?

Comment: I think it will make no difference, because the browser will parse the CSS file into its internal representation before rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will make no difference.

As @Strelok has commented, the browser will have to parse the CSS into its own interpretation either way anyway.